# Deleting Unsuitable Content from the Database Administrators Stack

Tags: discussion

For the backstory, see [Paul's post](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3099/deleting-useless-content-from-the-site) on the topic.

If you notice unsuitable content on the site, you can assist in removal.  Depending on your [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), you can assist by taking the following actions:

1. Copy-and-paste the URL for the unsuitable question into the ["Drop Question Queue"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85461/drop-question-queue) chat room.
2. If you are a user with 10k+ reputation,  click the "delete" link below the question to nominate the question for deletion.

If you want to help delete unsuitable content, please visit the [the "Drop Question Queue" chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85461/drop-question-queue), and consider voting to delete any of the questions listed that you think should be deleted from the site.  Remember, the questions listed in the chat room are posted there by other users of the site and should be considered suggestions - that is, there is no *requirement* for those questions to be deleted.  Think of the chat room like the other review queues - skip anything you don't feel comfortable with.  And, please, remember to be kind.

Room Owners in the ["Drop Question Queue" chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85461/drop-question-queue) can perform the following actions:

1. Move questions from the Drop Question Queue they feel present some value to the site and should *not* be deleted.  Please add a comment to the chat room saying why you think the item should stay on the main site.
2. Move questions from the Drop Question Queue that have been deleted from the main site into the [Dropped Questions Archive](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85472/dropped-question-archive) chat room.

For guidance about when or why to delete content, see the below quoted content, or ask in [The Heap™](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap--consultancy-) chat room if unsure.

From the [Moderator Tools Help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> When should I delete questions?
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are any good answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!
>
> Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as duplicates; they can serve as a signpost, directing users to useful answers on another question.
>
> It takes 3 votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However, the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers.
>
> You must wait for a question to be closed for 2 days before you can vote for deletion. This restriction is removed for trusted users when a post scores -3 or lower. If you feel a post should be deleted despite having lots of votes or for being new, please flag it for community moderator attention.

Comment: I wrote two queries in SEDE which I think are related to this topic. One is about dupes asked by same OP (more explanation in the query description: https://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/960986/duplicate-unanswered-questions-with-same-op-in-source-and-destination-list-of-so). The other is about questions from inactive users almost qualifying for auto-deletion (it work either ways; if it is a good Q upvote it and push it away from roomba https://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/960216/questions-from-inactive-users-with-one-vote-missing-to-automatic-deletion).